# UItableViewController in another UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm using a custom UITableViewController (myTblController) as a member variable in another UIViewController (MainViewController).

Iam using the addSubView to add the *tableview* of myTblController  on  MainViewController.

Is it possible to use  the **delegate and datasource** functions implemented in the myTblController instead of implementing table delegates function in MainViewController

in another words : i don't want to implement any TableView delegate or DataSource in my ViewController

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `dataSource` and `delegate` properties on the tableView are set independently of the actual parent view.  All you need to do is set them in interface builder, or in your code like this:

```
tableView.dataSource = myTblController;
tableView.delegate = myTblController;
```

`myTblController` being an actual instance of the class, I'm not sure if thats your class name or an instance name.

Comment: thanx , I've already tried this way , but only - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
is called .. any help ? 

thanx

Comment: are you returning a positive number from that function?  If thats being called, and the table view is visible, it should go next to numberOfRows inSection

Comment: Right. Try returning a value of 1 to show that the other delegate methods are called.

Comment: thanx allot guys , that worked , I've already tried it but maybe my view wasn't visible for some reason ,